# Best way to implement a Hibernate UserType after deprecations?

Tags: hibernate, usertype

I recently got the latest version of Hibernate and noticed that my UserTypes now have warnings about AbstractStandardBasicType's nullSafeGet(ResultSet,String) and nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement,T,int) methods being [deprecated](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5968?page=com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin%3afisheye-issuepanel) in favor of their corresponding methods that take a SessionImplementor argument.  The problem is that when you implement a UserType, the SessionImplementor doesn't get passed to you the way that is does in BasicType, CompositeUserType, etc.

I checked the Hibernate manual to see if there was an updated example.  Their UserType example uses get/set instead of nullSafeGet/nullSafeSet, but those methods were also deprecated in favor of versions that take a SessionImplementor.  So, it seems like even Hibernate's official UserType example is using deprecated methods, which leads me to wonder two things:

1. Is there a good way to get the SessionImplementor from within the UserType?
2. If it isn't practical to get the SessionImplementor from within UserType, and I don't want to write my own nullSafeGet/nullSafeSet, should I abandon UserType in favor of one of its alternatives?  What are the practical differences between UserType and, for example, BasicType?

Comment: There is a conversation on this topic in the hibernate-dev mailing list: [here](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2011-February/006030.html)

Comment: Is there a solution to this issue in 4.1.0.Final? It doesn't appear so...

Comment: I wish I could tell you.  I migrated to JPA and am sticking to the standard JPA annotations, which unfortunately don't support anything like UserTypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Ryan Ransford for his comment on my original question.  Although it's not really a solution to the problem, the [link](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2011-February/006030.html) he provided from the Hibernate developers mailing list explains why no solution is available.

> A non-deprecated alternative cannot be provided in 3.6.x, because doing 
>   so would break implementations of UserType.

Considering that these are just deprecation warnings, it doesn't make sense to invest too much time in a workaround that will be obsolete when the next non-maintenance release is available. Unfortunately, the next big release is 4.0, not 3.7, so migrating might be a little more involved.

Comment: Ok and..? So if I am migrating from v3.something to v4.something what do I do about my UserType's nullSafeGet/nullSafeSet methods that are now deprecated?

Comment: @KyleM I ended up migrating to a strict JPA approach and couldn't say for certain.  In the Hibernate 4.2 JavaDocs, I see that the deprecated methods have been removed but there are still nullSafeGet()/Set() methods that take a SessionImplementor.  I assume your UserType would implement those methods instead but I can't comment on the proper approach, as I've never done it myself.