# What to pass to UserType, BlobType.setPreparedStatement session parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/09/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/

I am attempting to defined a customer serialization UserType that mimics, the XStreamUserType referenced and provided here:

http://code.google.com/p/aphillips/source/browse/commons-hibernate-usertype/trunk/src/main/java/com/qrmedia/commons/persistence/hibernate/usertype/XStreamableUserType.java

My serializer outputs a bytearray that should presumably written to a Blob. I was going to do:

```
public class CustomSerUserType extends DirtyCheckableUserType {
    protected SerA ser=F.g(SerA.class);
    public Class<Object> returnedClass() {
        return Object.class;
    }
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] {Types.BLOB};
    }
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet,String[] names,Object owner) 
        throws HibernateException,SQLException {
        if()
    }
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement,Object value,int index) 
        throws HibernateException,SQLException {
        BlobType.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement,ser.ser(value),index);
    }
}
```

Unfortunetly, the BlobType.nullSafeSet method requires the session. So how does one define a UserType that gets access to a servlet requests session?

EDIT: There is a discussion of the issue here and it doesn't appear there is a solution: [Best way to implement a Hibernate UserType after deprecations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083768/best-way-to-implement-a-hibernate-usertype-after-deprecations)

Comment: There is a discussion of this issue here and it doesn't appear there is a solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083768/best-way-to-implement-a-hibernate-usertype-after-deprecations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved in the 4.1 API in the UserType interface.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/

The method signature of UserType passes the SessionImplementor to nullSafeGet and set.

Bonus tip: Make sure to look at the current Javadocs.