# Hibernate 4, alternative way for implement UserType

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to implement the UserType interface for use a custom type in hibernate.

I seen that the UserType is deprecated in hibernate 4, so there are other way to do it or it can't be done?

Of course I searched on Google and in Stackoverflow but i not found nothing that help me.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate 4 are you refering to? In 4.2.8 `UserType` is not deprecated - as well as in the current 4.3.6, at least according to the doc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083768/best-way-to-implement-a-hibernate-usertype-after-deprecations

Comment: @Thomas The version that I use is 4.3.6The version I'm using is 4.3.6; I have follow a guide for implement UserType for Hibernate 3 and of course it doesn't work. Have you a link of documentation or a guide?

Comment: Well, you basically just implement `UserType` and put a `@Type("fcqn.of.your.Usertype")` on the properties that should use it. If you want to read more, check Hibernate's documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom

Comment: @Thomas ok nice, I have last question... I have to implements that class for store the ID of an enumeration. When I need to query that table I must use the new Custom type or the smallint type stored in the table? there are performance problem?

Comment: Well, I don't think there's much of a performance problem to worry about. We're doing something similar using a bigint, so if your ids are small enough a smallint should be ok. After all, a user type is just a non-standard mapping between one or more columns of the provided database types and a Java object. So "custom" only applies to the Hibernate side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas's comments I have implemented the interface provided by Hibernate that is CompositeUserType.
It allow the use of your custom type in the HQL. I haven't noticed a drop of performance while I gained the semplicity to have the enum mapped automatically.

You need only read this doc https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom