# Trying to upgrade my WebApplication to java17,hibernate6x and spring6x but getting below issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-17, tomcat10

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryInformix' defined in class path resource [spring/application-bean.xml]: class org.hibernate.type.ComponentType cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicType (org.hibernate.type.ComponentType and org.hibernate.type.BasicType are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @4d847d32)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.type.ComponentType cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicType (org.hibernate.type.ComponentType and org.hibernate.type.BasicType are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @4d847d32)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to implement a Hibernate UserType after deprecations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083768/best-way-to-implement-a-hibernate-usertype-after-deprecations)

Comment: It's not a problem with the update to Java 17 and you would notice it yourself if you updated to Java 17 first.